# Android - Implement singleton with RoboGuice

Tags: android, singleton, roboguice

How can I implement a singleton in Android using RoboGuice? I would like to have a class that has a method "getInstance" that returns an instance of the class.

This is my solution:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class SingletonObject {
    @Inject
    private static SingletonObject s;

    private SingletonObject(){
        //do something
    }

    public static final SingletonObject getInstance(){
        return s;
    }
}
```

It could be a good solution?

Comment: `s` is initializated using `@Inject` because it is possible to inject a field of type SingletonObject or use the method `getInstance()` indifferently.

Comment: Please check out some examples on [Singletons And ContextSingletons](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Singletons-And-ContextSingletons) - these can shed some more light.